# Is php soap header encrypted?

Tags: php, encryption, soap

I've made a soap call using our own php api. The soap call requires us to send username/password in the soap header, and they only use http, no https.

Does this mean that without changes i would send our header info in cleartext, free for anyone to dump? Or is it encrypted by php itself?

Comment: I would be very surprised if any encryption happened at that level. That's not part of the SOAP protocol. I would recommend pushing your partner to provide an HTTPS endpoint.

Comment: PHP doesn't encrypt anything. and the SOAP xml itself isn't encrypted either. The CONTENTS of a soap tag may be encrypted, but that's up to the code to make it so. The only way the entire soap envelope gets crypted is if you're using SSL

Comment: @Chris Sounds right, i just wanted to be sure that's really how it worked. I'll contact the partner and see if they aren't ready to move to https.

Comment: Cool, thanks @MarcB, that sounds logical.

Comment: yes, it's basically traveling "in the clear"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using http, the entire contents of the request will be in plaintext, including the SOAP headers.  You need to use https to make it secure.

SOAP requests are just normal http requests, with a XML structure in the body.  It's easily viewable by anyone inspecting the traffic.